# Doctrine, setMaxResults, and get the number of result like setMaxResults hadnt been given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a usual querybuilder:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select()->setMaxResults(10);
```

but actually I need the total number of records too. Its a paginator-thing btw. How to do it elegantly? Should I run a second COUNT query too?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you need two queries

Comment: Or you can use [Doctrine's Paginator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) where you can access both

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine ships with a [pagination tool](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/pagination.html), which I would recommend to use. And yes, it perform two or three queries (depends on flag `$fetchJoinCollection`).

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('x')
    ->select()
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getQuery();

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false);

$totalRecords = $paginator->count();

foreach ($paginator as $entry) {
    $entry->getId();
}
```